# My Minecraft Won't let me break blocks in Survival

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

This is a highly talked about question, so I would like answers from people who know how to fix this or people who at least think they know what to do. So I enter a brand new game of survival Minecraft with cheats OFF. The first thing I do is try to get some wood. But when I try to break it, it just reappears. It doesn't give me the block for about 5-8 seconds. It seems to have gotten worse. And the mobs are slow. I try to kill a pig and it floats in the air for a few seconds, then they fall to the ground and I hit them again. It takes ages to kill mobs, and sometimes they are impossible to kill. This started about when the first or second snapshot for 1.13 came out and seems to have gotten worse over time. I don't want to play on an older version because I want to play in 1.13. What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

This is basically in-game lag. Your system doesn't have enough resources to run your game efficiently. You can solve this by trying several things:

1. Reduce the strain on your system resources, by lowering the in-game performance:

- Decrease your [render distance](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Options#Video_Settings).
- Reduce your graphics settings. This can be done with a lot of the settings like using "simple graphics", turning clouds off, smooth lighting, etc.

2. [Increase your RAM allowance for Mineraft](https://www.wikihow.com/Allocate-More-RAM-to-Minecraft) (if you have the available resources). This is one of the most likely causes for in-game lag.
3. Close other programs. People who record their gaming are one of the biggest victims for this, since recording requires a lot of RAM as well. If you have a lot of other things open at the same time, they will all be using your PC's RAM, which means Minecraft suffers.

Comment: How do i Increase my RAM?

Comment: @Spacial follow the link I have provided. I will need to elaborate in the answer later

Comment: You may also want to wait several seconds before doing anything once you spawn into a brand new world to allow the system time to generate all the visible chunks around your spawn.